# how to access buttons from fragment activity in another fragment activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I created a tabbed view in my project. there are three fragment activities

1. Home_fragment
2. Category_fragment
3. Favorite_fragment

I call the YouTube API in `Home_fragment` that displays the YouTube playlist.

Now I want to add three buttons in my `Category_fragment`. When I call on the 1st button, that will show me another playlist of video in `Home_fragment` as button 2 and button 3.

How can I create a method for the button in `Home_fragment` which can call from `Category_fragment`?

---

I did this code for my last project in which I call buttons from a drawer that displays the list in the `MainActivity`.

How can do the same like this, but put the buttons in my `Category_fragment` and call them in `Home_fragment`?

```
@Override


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        getVideosPlaylist home = new getVideosPlaylist();
        int id = item.getItemId();
        menu_id = id;

        if (id == R.id.nav_main) {
            url = url_home;
            main_toolbar =toolbar;
            main_toolbar.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());
            videos.clear();
            no_fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            home.execute();
        }if (id == R.id.nav_catone) {

            url = url_one;
            catone = toolbar;
            catone.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());
            videos.clear();
            no_fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            home.execute();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the fragment, you can set a tag which you can use to find it later:

```
Fragment fragment = YOUR FRAGMENT HERE;

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_content, fragment, "YOUR TAG HERE").commit();
```

To find it:

```
 Fragment fragment = (YOUR FRAGMENT)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR TAG HERE");
```

Then you access the method:

```
fragment.yourMethod();
```

It's important to make your method public so you can use it outside the class. Also, if you are not using compatibility, you can use getFragmentManager instead.